# How to use r2-score as a loss function in LightGBM?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, xgboost, loss-function, lightgbm

I am trying to implement a custom loss function in LightGBM for a regression problem. The intrinsic metrics do not help me much, because they penalise for outliers... Is there any way to use `r2_score` from `sklearn` as a loss function for LightGBM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R^2$ [is just a rescaling of](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/250735/232706) mean squared error, [the default loss function](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#objective) for LightGBM; so just run as usual.  (You could use another builtin loss (MAE or Huber loss?) instead in order to penalize outliers less.)

Comment: Thanks so much!! I completely forgot about the fact that it is similar to MSE!